# Why does kirchoffs voltage law hold in AC circuits?

Tags: electromagnetism

We came across the more general form of faradays law in my EM lecture:

$\oint E \cdot \,dl=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\int B \cdot dA)$

Pretty sure this is me misunderstanding magnetic fields in circuit theory, but in the case of a DC circuit, B is constant and so the rhs of the equation is 0, which gives KVL, the sum of the potential differences in a closed loop = 0. If the currents are varying, so will the magnetic fields they generate. In which case I can't see why in AC circuits KVL holds as the RHS no longer = 0. Can someone explain where my  reasoning has gone wrong.

Edit:

I am more specifically asking where my reasoning has gone wrong. I am already aware that it is valid under ideal circuit theory as an approximation to what really happens.

Comment: I am more specifically asking about my incorrect reasoning rather than whether or not it is actually valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any moment, $B(r,t)=\alpha(r) I(t)$ thanks to Biot-Savart. Then $\int_{\Omega} B\cdot dA = \beta I(t)$ with constant $\beta$. Let's write this back into your equation:
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} E\cdot dl=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\,(\beta I(t))=-\beta \dot{I}$$
We know that $\int_{\partial\Omega} E\cdot dl=\Delta V$ for any electrical effect, so
$$\Delta V=-\beta \dot{I}$$

Does this ring a bell? This is the equation for an inductive element. Therefore, for AC and DC alike, any circuit also has an (parasitic) inductive (and also resistive, capacitive)  properties. But, again, in *ideal* circuit theory, we consider these parasitic effects to be zero.